# Built game looks duller than what is seen in the editor

Tags: unity-game-engine

I built my unity game through Xcode into an iOS device for testing, and the colors look duller and more pastel-like than in the game view in the editor. The exact same thing has also happened on a modern android device. How can I make it so that the colors as seen in the built game better reflect the colors in the editor?

---

EDIT: I have sent a file to my phone and found out that the phone perceives colors differently than my monitor. I'm sorry if I'm asking for quite a bit here, but... is there any way to make the game look as I intend it to? The fact that I never see exactly how my game will turn out seems kinda... awkward. Thanks.

Comment: You might wanna look into Color Spaces. If I knew more, I'd point you further.

Comment: Also, mobile shaders are often simpler and use lower resolution textures.

Comment: Yeah basically you're stuck. And you should be looking at the problem from a different angle: everyone will have different screens of varying quality and you can't do anything about it. So instead of making sure one device is perfect, make sure most devices look reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you already tried this, but you might want to use Unity Remote for your iOS device, so you can check the color differences in real time instead of having to build it every time.

But other than what the comments said, it sounds like you should try to adjust your monitor's display settings for better color correlation between the built game and the one in the editor.

Comment: I assume you're right. After fiddling with Unity Remote, I found that there was nothing I could do to the colors themselves to make it look like what it looks like in the editor. It seems that the hardware simply doesn't allow it.